# Cannot connect to amazon ec2 from Mac OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2

I'm experiencing a strange problem. I cannot connect to amazon ec2 from my Mac OS 10.8. but I can easily connect from Linux/Windows machine. I cant even browse the webpage hosted on amazone ec2. I have tried from another Mac machine and my iPhone. result was same. couldn't connect . any idea?

Comment: Might have something to do with your DNS.  But we're going to need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: I'm able to ping to that IP. but connection to all other ports failed. Also tried with the host name. It is resolving to correct IP. I don't think it's DNS related.I have tried to load the site using IP, but that too failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing all firewall rules from amazon portal fixed the issue. But my server is wide open to public now!